# How to make auto keyboard using arduino nano V3.0 ATmega 328P ?

Tags: arduino-nano, shields, usb, keyboard

I have an Arduino Nano v3.0 ATmega328p board. I want to make an auto keyboard that types in a string when its plugged in. I have googled and found that these chips doesn't support that feature unlike "pro micro". keyboard.h is not supported with this chips. So is there any alternative way to use it as a HID and emulate keyboard inputs using any other additional shield other than using the built in USB port. Im a noob in this field, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can emulate USB on the atmega328. Look at the VUSB project. You just need a few resistors, diodes, and a USB cable.

Comment: I found this link : http://www.practicalarduino.com/projects/virtual-usb-keyboard Is that what you've been looking for?

Comment: Thank you @Gerben If you could give me some useful links so that i can get the basic codes, that would help me :)

Comment: Just google "vusb" and "vusb keyboard". Maybe some of the Adafruit guides for their pro trinket which uses VUSB. I'm currently on my mobile so linking is kind of difficult.